# Using Boost for Android throws error while compiling

Tags: android, c++, boost, android-ndk, java-native-interface

This is the error I get when using Boost library for Android. I am using Android NDK r8e and boost 1.53 and followed [this tutorial](https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/Boost-for-Android).

```
/home/tassilo/android-ndks/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lgnustl_static
/home/tassilo/android-ndks/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/boost/lib//libboost_regex-gcc-mt-1_53.a(instances.o): in function boost::object_cache<boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char>, boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char> >::do_get(boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char> const&, unsigned int):/home/tassilo/android-ndks/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/stl_list.h:1508: error: undefined reference to 'std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_transfer(std::__detail::_List_node_base*, std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
/home/tassilo/android-ndks/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/boost/lib//libboost_regex-gcc-mt-1_53.a(instances.o): in function boost::object_cache<boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char>, boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char> >::do_get(boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char> const&, unsigned int):/home/tassilo/android-ndks/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/stl_list.h:1508: error: undefined reference to 'std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_transfer(std::__detail::_List_node_base*, std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
/home/tassilo/android-ndks/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/boost/lib//libboost_regex-gcc-mt-1_53.a(instances.o): in function boost::object_cache<boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char>, boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char> >::do_get(boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char> const&, unsigned int):/home/tassilo/android-ndks/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/stl_list.h:1516: error: undefined reference to 'std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)'
/home/tassilo/android-ndks/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: jni/boost/lib//libboost_regex-gcc-mt-1_53.a(instances.o): in function boost::object_cache<boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char>, boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char> >::do_get(boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_base<char> const&, unsigned int):/home/tassilo/android-ndks/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/include/bits/stl_list.h:1532: error: undefined reference to 'std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libusit.so] Error 1
```

This is how my make file looks like:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include ./jni/opencv/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE           := usit
LOCAL_SRC_FILES        := cr.cpp

LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/include/boost-1_53
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/lib/ -lboost_system-gcc-mt-1_53 -lboost_regex-gcc-mt-1_53 -lboost_filesystem-gcc-mt-1_53 -lboost_date_time-gcc-mt-1_53 \
-L$(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi \
-lgnustl_static


include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

As suggested in the tutorial I am specifying the path to NDK Root. I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and defined the NDK_ROOT variable in .bashrc and .profile like this:

```
export NDK_ROOT=${HOME}/android-ndks/android-ndk-r8e
```

I appreciate any help.

EDIT:

This is my Application.mk

```
APP_PLATFORM          := android-8
APP_ABI               := armeabi-v7a
APP_OPTIM             := debug
NDK_DEBUG             := 1

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.6
APP_STL               := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS          := -fexceptions -frtti
```

Comment: Does `sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/libs/armeabi` path really exist? Doesn't it look like `sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi`?

Comment: Hi thanks I guess this solved it! I am now able to compile my project. But when trying to run it as Application I'm getting an UnsatisfiedLinkerError telling me that opencv_java.so does not exist. It's the other library I have to use to. But I guess that's another question

Comment: Well, you have to link that library too. See `android-ndk/docs` for details and examples.

Comment: I'm doing this by including the given .mk file. See above. `include ./jni/opencv/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk`

Answer (score 2):

To use **gnustl** (static or shared), you need parameter `APP_STL`. Usually, we set it in **Application.mk**, but you can also set it on command line (do this with care, never mix different values).

I recommend to install the latest NDK, and not use the outdated 4.6 toolchain.

Example of **Application.mk**:

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.8
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
```

Comment: Hi!I have to use another library as well and as I am trying to port an existing project I will stick to the recommended library versions which are both compatible only with NDK r8e. I also added my already existing Applictaion.mk in my question. With the Comment of Igor I was able to compile, but not to run my App because of OpenCV error

Comment: OK, cool. **1)** you probably don't need to explicitly reference `_gnustl_` in your `Android.mk` file.  **2)** You must explicitly `load("opencv_java")` in your Java code before you load `libusit.so`.

Comment: I have to do this the same way I load my own lib? I already opened another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25869325/native-opencv-in-android-unsatisfiedlinkerror-libopencv-java-so-not-found. Come and collect some rep ;)