# Native OpenCV in Android UnsatisfiedLinkError libopencv_java.so not found

Tags: android, c++, opencv, boost, android-ndk

I've seen similar posts but none were giving correct answers.

Setup:

```
Linux Ubuntu 14.04
Android NDK r8e
Boost 1.53
OpenCV 2.4.9
```

While compiling I got this warning:

```
Compile++ thumb  : usit <= wahet.cpp
SharedLibrary  : libusit.so
/home/tassilo/android-ndks/android-ndk-r8e/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.6/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: warning: hidden symbol '__aeabi_atexit' in /home/tassilo/android-ndks/android-ndk-r8e/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi-v7a/libgnustl_static.a(atexit_arm.o) is referenced by DSO jni/opencv/sdk/native/jni/../libs/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_java.so
Install        : libusit.so => libs/armeabi-v7a/libusit.so
```

I am not yet trying to call my C++ code, all I am doing is creating the library which results in this error:

```
09-16 14:34:59.189: V/IRISREC(654): Native code library failed to load.
09-16 14:34:59.189: V/IRISREC(654): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1936]:    36 could not load needed library 'libopencv_java.so' for 'libusit.so' (load_library[1091]: Library 'libopencv_java.so' not found)
```

Here is my **Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
NDK_ROOT := /home/tassilo/android-ndks/android-ndk-r8e


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include ./jni/opencv/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE           := usit
LOCAL_SRC_FILES        := wahet.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES:= ./jni/opencv/sdk/native/jni/include
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -I$(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/include/boost-1_53
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/lib/ -lboost_system-gcc-mt-1_53 -lboost_regex-gcc-mt-1_53 -lboost_filesystem-gcc-mt-1_53 -lboost_date_time-gcc-mt-1_53 \
-L$(NDK_ROOT)/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.6/libs/armeabi \
-lgnustl_static \
-L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_PLATFORM          := android-8
APP_ABI               := armeabi-v7a
APP_OPTIM             := debug
NDK_DEBUG             := 1

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.6
APP_STL               := gnustl_static
APP_CPPFLAGS          := -fexceptions -frtti
```

and the library load in my **MainAcitvity.java**

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("usit");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
    }
}
```

So the error is thrown in my first catch block. 
The need library files are in my folder

```
./jni/opencv/sdk/native/libs/ -armeabi/ -armeabi-v7a etc.
```

I am failing around with all this stuff since several days.. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding `hidden symbol '__aeabi_atexit'`, the [answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14881/hidden-symbol-__aeabi_atexit-in-is-referenced-by/) at **opencv.org**  suggests to use `gnustl_shared` instead of `gnustl_static`.

This fit my personal experience with opencv_java, and means that the Java code must change accordingly:

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared"); // added
        System.loadLibrary("opencv_java");
        System.loadLibrary("usit");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Exception: " + e);
    }
}
```

**Android.mk**

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
include ./jni/opencv/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_MODULE           := usit
LOCAL_SRC_FILES        := wahet.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
  $(LOCAL_PATH)/opencv/sdk/native/jni/include \
  $(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/include/boost-1_53

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -L$(LOCAL_PATH)/boost/lib/ \
  -lboost_system-gcc-mt-1_53 \
  -lboost_regex-gcc-mt-1_53 \
  -lboost_filesystem-gcc-mt-1_53 \
  -lboost_date_time-gcc-mt-1_53 \
  -llog

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**Application.mk**

```
APP_PLATFORM          := android-8
APP_ABI               := armeabi-v7a
APP_OPTIM             := debug
NDK_DEBUG             := 1

NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.6
APP_STL               := gnustl_shared
APP_CPPFLAGS          := -fexceptions -frtti
```

Comment: `09-16 15:04:59.749: V/IRISREC(979): Native code library failed to load.
09-16 15:04:59.749: V/IRISREC(979): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java: findLibrary returned null`

Comment: Did you have a look at the warning I got while compiling? Maybe it has something to do with it

Comment: Tried this as well. Now I'm getting errors like `09-17 11:51:48.318: V/IRISREC(22294): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.irisrec-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.irisrec-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null` same for the gnustl_shared. So I tried replacing `
APP_STL               := gnustl_static` with `
APP_STL               := gnustl_shared`in my Application.mk and removed it from Android.mk. Now only the gnustl_shared error is gone.

Comment: Hey I just found out I have different errors on device (Android) and on emulator. In the emulator (Android 4.0) it is the same error as in my first comment. I added also armeabi to my Application.mk to make sure my SGS4 (Android 4.4) is supported.

Comment: No :(
I it's the second error I posted in coments now. As a friend of mine recommended I just tried to copy the opencv_java.so to data/data/my.app/libs and system/lib but both not working as well.

Comment: `libopencv_java.so` should be packaged in your APK, together with `libusit.so` and `libgnustl_shared.so`. You need `OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on` in your **Android.mk** before you include **OpenCV.mk**.

Comment: That fixed it! Thanks very much. Please add it to your answer as well